# How to increment/decrements viewport meta values(initial scale, max scale or min scale) on every button click?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

Im developing phonegap app in that I have used meta tag values through Javascript , I need a requirement to change meta tag values(initial scale, max scale or min scale) on button clicks. Its changing only one times after that does not work(change). I am running it in Android 4.0.4 devices and using Phonegap 2.9.0
Below is my Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Onload");
});
var scale = 1.0;
function zoomIn(){
    scale++;
    if (screen.width < 500) {

        $('#meta-viewport').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=' + scale
        + ', maximum-scale=' + scale + ', minimum-scale=' + scale + ', user-scalable=yes');
    }
}

function zoomOut() {
    scale--;
    if (screen.width < 500) {

        $('#meta-viewport').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=' + scale
        + ', maximum-scale=' + scale + ', minimum-scale=' + scale + ', user-scalable=yes');
    }
}
```

Below is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum scale=1.0,
            minimum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,
            height=device-height,target-densitydpi=devicedpi" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_v1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="background" src="img/bgImg.png" style="position: absolute; z-index:-1;" />
        <img id="carImg1" src="img/up.png"
            style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 100px; z-index:1;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Please anybody help me to get resolve this..What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like you are hiding the original declaration `scale` by redeclaring it within the two `if` blocks. Remove the `var` keyword (or the entire statement) within your function declarations. In JavaScript, they are treated as if you had declared them at the top of the function.
2. Change the selectors `#meta-viewport` to `meta[name="viewport"]`.

Comment: Removed and tested again Stil same problem. It does not get changing

Comment: I don't see anything in your document that matches the selector `#meta-viewport`. Perhaps you meant `meta[name="viewport"]`?

Comment: Yes I will check and come back to you. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Yes i have changed it.. now its working fine. One more problem sir.. With background image buttons also get zooming. Is any there way to change scale for only particular images?

Comment: Good to hear. I will update my answer. As far as the background images go, I only know that you can modify `background-size`.

Comment: background-size of which? We can adjust buttons size when scale increased?